# Programa sobre sucesiones recurrentes en python

Tags: python, python-3.x

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]He estado luchando con un programa de codificación para obtener un valor que depende de un valor calculado previamente: es un programa que consiste en una sucesión recurrente. La imagen se adjunta a continuación.

He probado el siguiente código, pero no es lo que estoy buscando.

```
def alfa(n):
    itery = 0
    i = 0
    while i < n:
        X_0 = ((i-1)+1)**(1/2)
        i += 1
    return X_0
```

El problema es que el resultado no es el que esperaba. Por ejemplo para X0 = 1 y X1 usa el valor X0 y aplicó la fórmula y lo mismo para calcular X2 usa el valor X1 y lo pone en la fórmula.

Si puedes ayudarme te lo agradecería.
Muchas gracias por tu ayuda

Añado esto es lo que quiero hacer pero no sé como acumular el valor anterior y seguir utilizándolo para cualquier número n

```
def alfa(n):
    itery = 0
    i = 0
    while i < n:
        x_0 = 1
        x_1 = ((x_0)+1)**(1/2)
        x_2 = ((x_1)+1)**(1/2)
        i += 1
    return x_2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Olvida los subíndices `X_0`, `X_1`, etc...

En el fondo `X_0` significa "valor de `x` antes de la primera iteración", es decir, antes de entrar al bucle, y `x_1` significa "valor de `x` en la primera iteración", etc..

Si te olvidas por el momento de esos subíndices y simplemente le llamas `x` tendrías lo siguiente:

- Antes de entrar al bucle `x=1`
- Dentro del bucle, el nuevo valor de `x` se calcula a partir del valor que antes tenía `x` con la expresión `(x+1)**(1/2)`. El resultado de eso se asigna de nuevo a `x`.
- Una vez hayas completado todas las iteraciones, el valor de `x` será el resultado buscado.

Con estas ideas el bucle quedará así:

```
def alfa(n):
  i = 0
  x = 1
  while i < n:
    x = (x+1)**(1/2)
    i += 1
  return x
```

#### Notas

- En vez de un `while` puedes usar un `for`
- En vez de `1/2` puedes usar `0.5` para que el código sea válido también para Python2 (ya que en Python2 el operador `/` hace la división entera, por lo que `1/2` daría 0 en vez de 0.5).

Por tanto:

```
def alfa(n):
  x = 1
  for i in range(n):
    x = (x+1)**0.5
  return x
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias de verdad, estaba totalmente bloqueado y al final era más fácil de lo que parecía

Answer (score 1):

Una solución:

```
from math import sqrt
def alpha(n):
    x = 1
    for i in range(n):
        x = sqrt(x + 1)
    return x
```

**Demo**

```
for n in range(10):
    print(f"{n} = {alpha(n)}")
```

produce:

```
0 = 1
1 = 1.4142135623730951
2 = 1.5537739740300374
3 = 1.5980531824786175
4 = 1.6118477541252516
5 = 1.616121206508117
6 = 1.6174427985273905
7 = 1.617851290609675
8 = 1.6179775309347393
9 = 1.6180165422314876
```

Answer (score 1):

La computación del número áureo se adapta perfectamente a la siguiente solución recursiva:

```
from math import sqrt


def alfa(n):
    if n < 1:
        return 1
    return sqrt(alfa(n - 1) + 1)
```

Acá se entiende que, para números mayores o iguales a 1, esta función devuelve la raíz cuadrada del resultado de la misma función pero computada con el número anterior en la sucesión, más 1.

Una pequeña nota: La legibilidad importa. Por lo tanto también te sugiero importar la función `sqrt` del módulo `math` para revelar claramente la intención del código a cualquiera que lo lea.